# Delete Realm Object and update relationships

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, realm

**UPDATE**

If I change my delete function to this:

```
function deleteResNote(reservation, note_idx) {
  realm.write(() => {
    reservation.notes.splice(note_idx, 1)
  })
}
```

Everything works fine. No errors, and the UI updates accordingly.

Why do I need to delete my notes *through* my reservation object? Why doesn't realm allow me to delete my Notes objects directly?

---

My app deals with **Tasks**, which have **Reservations**, which have **Notes**. I'm working on the ability to delete a note.

My notes render in a `ListView`. When the cell is tapped, I pass the Note object (Realm Object) through to my deletion method, and ultimately call:

```
function deleteResNote(noteObj) {
  realm.write(() => {
    realm.delete(noteObj)
  })
}
```

After this delete, this method triggers the following error:

> Error: Accessing object of type Notes which has been deleted

The component which holds my `ListView` is set up to listen for the realm change event, and the same method used to render for the first time is used again to re-render the updated notes. I think it's important to point out that in this method, Notes are accessed through the parent Task object.

```
handleReservationNotes = taskId => {
  let dataBlob = {}
  let sectionIDs = []
  let rowIDs = []
  let reservations = []
  const details = Tasks.getTask(taskId)

  Object.values(details.reservations).forEach((reservation, i) => {
    reservations.push({ id: reservation.id, lead: reservation.lead_name })

    // manage our sections
      sectionIDs.push(reservation.id)

    dataBlob[reservation.id] = reservation.lead_name

    // manage our rows
    rowIDs[i] = []
    Object.values(reservation.notes).forEach((note, j) => {
      rowIDs[i].push(j)
      dataBlob[`${reservation.id}:${j}`] = note
    })
  })

  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs),
    reservations,
    selectedReservationId:reservations[0].id,
  })
}
```

It seems as though I'm properly deleting the note from the database, but my **Reservation** object seems to be still holding on to it.

How can I successfully delete a **Note** while updating all the appropriate relationships?

Comment: Does your list source update after the deletion?

Comment: @EranGoldin yes. I just updated my question with the function that's called when realm detects a change. at the bottom you can see how i'm resetting `state.datasource`

Comment: It sounds like you are running into https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4460#issuecomment-292884450 on realm-js side

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks. but I'm not listening for changes in specific objects, just changes to realm in general. The notification was being delivered successfully. My problem was that deleting the note object directly  was throwing the error. If I delete it though the Reservation object, things work fine.